# Sentence are tokenized to words in pandas but the indexes are from 0 till length of first sentence and again for second sentence it starts from 0

Tags: python

I have a python df,

```
     DF1 = Index  Words    Tags
             0      I       O
             1     Love     B
             2     India    I
             0    Flowers   B
             1      are     O
             2   Beautiful  B
```

I want the output to be,

```
   DF1 = Index  Words    Tags   Sent
             0      I       O    1
             1     Love     B    1
             2     India    I    1
             0    Flowers   B    2
             1      are     O    2
             2   Beautiful  B    2
```

I would want to get a df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, [`pandas.DataFrame.Shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to create a boolean mask & apply [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum).

```
df['Sent'] = (df.Index - df.Index.shift()).lt(0).cumsum() + 1
```

---

```
   Index      Words Tags  Sent
0      0          I    O     1
1      1       Love    B     1
2      2      India    I     1
3      0    Flowers    B     2
4      1        are    O     2
5      2  Beautiful    B     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it throws an error ''
NotImplementedError: Not supported for type Int64Index''.. Not sure why. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You need to tokenize the whole sentence. Concat both first.